# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollDict.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object refe

Tags: android, crash, appcelerator

I am having a simple tableview in my App and when i click on it the app crashes on Android.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollDict.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiUIView.composeContentDescription(TiUIView.java:2137)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiUIView.applyContentDescription(TiUIView.java:2111)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiUIView.applyAccessibilityProperties(TiUIView.java:2174)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiUIView.setNativeView(TiUIView.java:346)
        at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.searchview.TiUISearchView.(TiUISearchView.java:44)
        at ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.SearchViewProxy.createView(SearchViewProxy.java:40)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:580)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:549)
        at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUITableView.processProperties(TiUITableView.java:154)
        at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.setModelListener(KrollProxy.java:1275)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:595)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:586)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:549)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:602)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:586)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:549)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:602)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:586)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:549)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:602)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:586)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:549)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleAdd(TiViewProxy.java:791)
        at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:268)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: The object you’re calling the .get() method on, might probably be null. That explains the NullPointerException. Could you verify that?

Comment: It's look like the error cause by some function receive null value. I sugges you to add the part of your code and give some description of your code and make the error message easy looking

Comment: It works fine on IOS if I remove the  SearchView if the os is android the code runs fine. I am hitting a wall and unable to identify the issue. I am just closing the top window and going back to the old screen nothing fancy about the back button.

Comment: ```if (OS_ANDROID) {
    var search = Ti.UI.Android.createSearchView({
     hintText: "Search Facility"
    });
    tbl_facility_list.search = search; //this line crashes 
    tbl_facility_list.searchAsChild = false;
    tbl_facility_list.setFilterAttribute('title');
```